# assign javascript array value to angularjs variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
obj = ['sha','abc','xyz] //javascript array

function myclrt($scope) //this angular js function
{
    $Scope.one = obj[0]; // obj[0] is not being assinged to scope.one
}
```

This is not working.

Comment: i want to assign 'sha'(viz obj[0]) to $scope.one (which is angularjs variable)

Comment: Typo, try `$scope` instead of `$Scope`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```
obj = ['sha','abc','xyz] //javascript array
function myclrt($scope) //this angular js function
{
   $scope.one = obj[0]; // Typo $Scope -> $scope
}
```